# Microsoft Translator widget doesn't translate buttons

Tags: microsoft-translator

I use Microsoft Translator widget on my site, and it generally works. However, some items on my page are not translated:

**Item1**

`<asp:FileUpload />`, which becomes:
`<input type="file" />`, which is displayed as untranslated English:
* Chrome: `"Choose a File..." | No file chosen`
* IE: `Browse...`
I guess this one depends on the browser's display language.

**Item2**

`<asp:Button Text="Submit something"`, which becomes:
`<input (...) type="submit" value="Submit something"`,
in which "Submit something" is not translated.

Is there any way I can get Microsoft Translator to translate these? I guess I could do the widget's work, call MT API myself and update the value (in the second case), but I'd really rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Translator only supports `<Button id="Button1" runat="server">My Button</ Button>` translations.  It doesn't translate the input type=button, asp:Button or telerik:Button nor any other flavor of buttons that you don't place the text for the button in between the tags.  Check this article out.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a840884b-4efe-4cd4-a598-0ca81842404c/widget-does-not-translate-button-text

I have been looking for a solution similar to what you are but I have found nothing.

So outside of changing all your buttons to this type I am assuming that we would need to use the api to do the translations.